# How is this result being given when it clearly does not meet the criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a full-text search to query company records based on their tags.

One of the companies has the following string in the `tags` field:

> Roofing Services B2B Construction Contractors & Services Construction Founded 1982 Acclaim Contracts established reputation throughout London South East delivering roofing general building projects safely time snag free budget Building Partnerships customer approach consultative considerate work extension team aim responsive flexible

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT
    company.domain,
    company.company_name,
    CONCAT_WS(
        ',',
        company.business_sector,
        company.tags
    ) AS 'tags',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        employee.employee_id SEPARATOR ','
    ) AS 'employee_ids',
    COUNT(employee.employee_id) AS 'employees',
    COUNT(ct_connections.id) AS 'already_connected',
    company.business_sector
FROM
    company
INNER JOIN employee ON company.domain = employee.domain
LEFT JOIN ct_connections ON employee.email = ct_connections.email
AND ct_connections.client_id = 1
WHERE
    MATCH (company.tags) AGAINST ('"xyz123 contracts"')
AND company.domain NOT IN (
    '@hotmail.com',
    '@gmail.com',
    '@aol.com'
)
GROUP BY
    company.domain
```

Now, from the tags I have shown you, it quite clearly **cannot** match `xyz123 contracts`, and yet somehow this result is being given to me? How?

Comment: Try to add explicitly the search modifier to see if changes the result. MATCH (company.tags) AGAINST ('xyz123 contracts'  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)

Comment: @pringi Nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe it matches the spaces?! I never used this, just an assumption.
Try ` IN BOOLEAN MODE` if you want to match the entire string.

Comment: ... which is only true in `BOOLEAN MODE`. So use it, as Jan proposed. If you don't use boolean mode, `"` has no effect.

Comment: Do you need to group by company_name/business_sector as well as or instead of domain?

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean search instead.

```
MATCH (company.tags) AGAINST ('+xyz123 +contracts"'IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This way both words must be present.

With your current syntax partial matches are also returned (contracts in your case).

See

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php

Comment: This would not work for phrases, it would end up matching `xyz123 random contracts`, no?

Comment: `MATCH ... AGAINST('+"xyz123 contracts"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`... perhaps?